# Is "wo war die geboren?" correct?

Tags: translation

> "Wo war dir geboren?"

As in "Where were you born?"

Is it correct? If not what is?

Comment: The title says *die*, while the text says *dir*? Which one are you asking about?

Comment: Wobei beides falsch ist.

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't; correct would be "Wo bist du geboren?" or "Wo sind Sie geboren?".

Comment: @NoahLeskron: Then delete your question. The problem does not exist anymore.

Comment: Und: "Wo wurdest Du geboren?" bzw. "Wo sind Sie geboren worden?".